# Binary with Arguments in AWS Lambda

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I have a Golang command line tool that is build from the code base for a project. For arguments sake, this executable is called `foo`. One of the sub-commands for this CLI uses a Lambda context adapter to server (https://github.com/akrylysov/algnhsa), this being executed through the command `foo serve`.

Typically for deploying Golang binaries to an AWS Lambda, you specify the executable name within the `zip` archive being uploaded, and the `main` function for the executable handles the Lambda invocations. For this use-case, I'm trying to find a way to have the Lambda function, on invocation, execution the equivalent of `foo serve`.

Is this something that's possible, to have an executable *with* arguments assigned as the handler for a Go runtime Lambda function?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I would like to run the function with some arguments like `maxRetries=10` or something like that. I have not yet found a way to get this to work ...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to specify how lambda is run, there is away to define custom runtime.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html

An example repo using custom runtime - https://github.com/b-b3rn4rd/aws-lambda-runtime-golang

Comment: So my deployment `zip` would have the CLI executable and a `bootstrap` script that just runs `./foo serve`?

Comment: @m_callens Usually yes. You need your executable to understand how AWS request works. The reference github project I gave you demonstrate this. In AWS page there is example with bash script.